# loading vuejs element on blade issue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

So, I am facing some problem on loading vuejs component on my blade engine. when I added vuejs component it either load the vuejs 'bootstrap' or load the `public/js/app.js` depending what is commented out. this is the app.blade.php code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Global Shopping Mall</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!-- <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" ></script>      -->

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-q3eWabyZPc1XTCmF+8/LuE1ozpg5xxn7iO89yfSOd5/oKvyqLngoNGsx8jq92Y8eXJ/IRxQbEC+FGSYxtk2oiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/src/jquery.exzoom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery.exzoom.js"></script>


    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" defer >

    <style>
        body{
            background-color: white;
        }
        .custom_navbar{
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm" style="height: 60px;">
            <img src="{{asset('images/gsm.jpg')}}" alt="GSM Logo" class width="150px" height="65px">
            <div class="container">
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('SignUp') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                            
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login as Guest') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                        
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a  class="nav-link" href="/home"><strong>Home<strong></a>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{"Hi, "}}{{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/user_profile">
                                        User Profile
                                    </a>
                                    <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="/product_details">
                                        Product Details
                                    </a> -->
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>
                                    

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        @if(Auth::check())
            @include('layouts.gsm_nav')
        @endif
        <main>
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        @extends('layouts.footer')
    </div>
    
    <style>
        .custom_nav{
            padding-right: 50px
        }
        /* .v-application--wrap {
            min-height: 0;
        } */
    </style>
    <script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if I comment this line
`script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`
then its load my blade style without vuejs element but if not then its load only vuejs not public script

heres my vuejs app.js code and bootstrap.js code
`app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');


window.Vue = require('vue');


// Main Screens Components
Vue.component('user-list', require('./components/UserList.vue').default);
Vue.component('main-screen', require('./components/Main.vue').default);

//  Streaming Components
Vue.component("broadcaster", require("./components/Broadcaster.vue").default);
Vue.component("viewer", require("./components/Viewer.vue").default);

// Vue.component('video-chat', require('./components/VideoChat.vue').default);

Vue.prototype.$userId = document.querySelector("meta[name='user-id']").getAttribute('content');


import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';



Vue.use(Vuetify); 

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});



Echo.private('chat')
  .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
    this.messages.push({
      message: e.message.message
    });
});
```

`bootstrap.js`

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

 import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
 
 window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
 });
```

this is the element code

```
<div class="app">
    <v-app>
        <main-screen user-name="{{ Auth::user()->name }}"></main-screen>
        
        <meta name="user-id" content="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
        <meta name="user-name" content="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <button class="open-button" type="button" onclick="openForm()"></button>
    
    </v-app>
</div>
```

[Want this style with vuejs element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAfSv.png)

[Red mark is the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtZAi.png)

i am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue I can see your code is you're putting your blade code inside `<div id="app"> </div>` but the thing is whenever you include `<script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>` it will remove your any html/blade code and put vue.js code inside that div.

So you've to do something like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>Global Shopping Mall</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <!-- <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" ></script>      -->

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-q3eWabyZPc1XTCmF+8/LuE1ozpg5xxn7iO89yfSOd5/oKvyqLngoNGsx8jq92Y8eXJ/IRxQbEC+FGSYxtk2oiw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/src/jquery.exzoom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery.exzoom.js"></script>


    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" defer >

    <style>
        body{
            background-color: white;
        }
        .custom_navbar{
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <-- put your blade/html content here -->

       <div id="app"></div>
       <-- Create a div with id of app to render vue.js content, like above -->
    </div>
    
    <style>
        .custom_nav{
            padding-right: 50px
        }
        /* .v-application--wrap {
            min-height: 0;
        } */
    </style>
    <script defer src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do let me know if you need any other help in same scenario.